# Update SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update a table on a specific row need some advice on my php statement

I use this statement to call the client's info

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="****"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_msisdn='$query'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

This works fine echoíng the information I need and able to alter it.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="control_clientupdated.php">
```

This referes to my action php script

Problem I need assistance with is how do i notify my action script to use the same id I ran the query on to update that row.

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET member_name='$member_name',     
member_surname='$member_surname', member_msisdn='$member_msisdn', cid='$cid',    
cofficenr='$cofficenr', cfax='$cfax',  e2mobile='$e2mobile' WHERE member_msisdn='$query'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I have placed the WHERE statement on the end of the update

Let me just state it shows done, but it did not update the table at all

Comment: Just pass value of `$id` in a hidden field.

Comment: Is the second section of php your "control_clientupdated.php" script?

Comment: depend where do you store id (somewhere in form?) but something in the line like $_POST['id'];

Comment: @Blue yes the second section is the action script supposed to update the sql, The first code is a echo where i can view and edit the information. the $id i get from a search value showing me a specific client information

Comment: use hidden input value like Rikesh suggested, and fetch it with POST on control_clientupdated.php script.

Comment: change 
WHERE msisdn='$query' 
to 
WHERE member_msisdn='$query' 
and check

Comment: Ok think that will work but could you let me know how to imput that hidden field this is one thing i have been batteling with as well

Comment: @arslaan I have done that it was a mistype from my side it removes the error on the action page but does not update the line

Comment: Trevor,making input hidden value -> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to store your ID into a hidden form element in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="control_clientupdated.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="member_msisdn" value="<?=$query?>" />
    ...
</form>
```

This will allow you to passthrough the value from your first php script.

Then in your `control_clientupdated.php` you need to use `$_POST` to recover your value.

```
// Store the $_POST value for my query ID
$query = $_POST['member_msisdn'] ;

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET member_name='$member_name',     
member_surname='$member_surname', member_msisdn='$member_msisdn', cid='$cid',    
cofficenr='$cofficenr', cfax='$cfax',  e2mobile='$e2mobile' WHERE member_msisdn='$query'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

This should be what you need - note that you cannot use `$_GET` to retrieve the variable passed by the form, as you are sending it with the `method="post"` attribute, you must use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Thanks Blue it worked great needed to tweak some things but working